# angularjs function not invoking mvc controller method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am trying to access my method through angularjs but when I click the button it hits the function but does not invoke the Controller actionresult but when I manually add the url in it then calls the method.

here is my angular code:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetEmployeeList?=' + search }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.customers = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('error');
    });

    }
```

and here is my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetEmployeeList(string search)
    {
        search = "Lourens";
        List<Quotation> quote = new List<Quotation>();
        using (SpecialHireEntities sp = new SpecialHireEntities())
        {
            var quotes = sp.Quotations.Where(x => x.ClientName == search).ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = quotes, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the url in the first line of JS should be

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetEmployeeList?search=' + search }).
```

rather than

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetEmployeeList?=' + search }).
```

With the code you mentioned, MVC model binding would never be able to find value for variable 'search' thus the request would not be resolved ending in an exception